# in D3.js is there any way bind the scroll event in both the x and y directions to panning the svg?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, d3.js, svg

Currently my d3 tree has a zoom behavior whenever I scroll up or down. I would like to replace that behavior with panning instead. Does anyone have any idea how I would go about this?

```
    // Define the zoom function for the zoomable tree
    function zoom() {
        svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    }

    // define the zoomListener which calls the zoom function on the "zoom" event constrained within the scaleExtents
    var zoomListener = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.1, 3,1]).on("zoom", zoom);

    // define the baseSvg, attaching a class for styling and the zoomListener
    var baseSvg = d3.select("#tree-container").append("svg")
        .attr("width", viewerWidth)
        .attr("height", viewerHeight)
        .attr("class", "overlay")
        .call(zoomListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to changing the default zoom functionality to pan. There were various resources I was able to find including a good post here on stackoverflow.

```
function panTo() {
    var current_translate = d3.transform(svgGroup.attr("transform")).translate;

    var dx = d3.event.wheelDeltaX + current_translate[0];
    var dy = d3.event.wheelDeltaY + current_translate[1];

    svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate(" + [dx,dy] + ")");
    d3.event.stopPropagation();
}

// Define the zoom function for the zoomable tree
function zoom() {
    svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}


// define the zoomListener which calls the zoom function on the "zoom" event constrained within the scaleExtents
var zoomListener = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.1, 3,1]).on("zoom", zoom);

// define the baseSvg, attaching a class for styling and the zoomListener
var baseSvg = d3.select("#tree-container").append("svg")
    .attr("width", viewerWidth)
    .attr("height", viewerHeight)
    .attr("class", "overlay")
    .call(zoomListener)
    .on("wheel.zoom",panTo) 
    .on("mousewheel.zoom", panTo)
    .on("DOMMouseScroll.zoom", panTo)
```